# Check value of a 2d array for different column indices in each row of 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have some a binary 2D numpy array (`prediction`) like:

```
[
[1 0 1 0 1 1],
[0 0 1 0 0 1],
[1 1 1 1 1 0],
[1 1 0 0 1 1],
]
```

Each row in the 2D array is the classification of a sentence as being certain categories, and each column in the 2D array corresponds to the classification of a category for that sentence. The categories (`categories` array) are `['A','B','C','D','E','F']` as an example.

I have another 2D array (`catIndex`) which contains the index of the value to check in each row, e.g.

```
[[0],
  [4],
  [5],
  [2]
]
```

for the 4 instances above.

What I want to do is now loop through the binary 2D array and for the column index specified for each sentence, check if it is a `1` or a `0`, and then append the corresponding category to a new array (`catResult = []`). If it is a `0`, I would append `"no_region"` to the new array.

So for example, in sentence 1, I look at index `0` of the sentence, and check if it is a `0` or `1`. It is a `1`, so I append `'A'` to my new array. In sentence 2, I look at index `4` of the sentence, and see it is a `0`, so I append `"no_region"` to the array.

Current code:

```
for index in catIndex:
        for i,sentence in enumerate(prediction):
            for j,binaryLabel in enumerate(sentence):
                if prediction[i][index]==1:
                    catResult.append(categories[index])
                else:
                    catResult.append("no_region")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the 2d array:

```
In [54]: M=[[1,0,1,0,1,1],[0,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1,1]]
In [55]: M=np.array(M)
```

Column index with `ind`, with [0,1,2,3] as the row index:

```
In [56]: ind=[0,4,5,2]    
In [57]: m=M[np.arange(len(ind)),ind]
In [58]: m
Out[58]: array([1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Map labels with `ind`:

```
In [59]: lbl=np.array(list('ABCDEF'),dtype=object)    
In [60]: res=lbl[ind]
In [61]: res
Out[61]: array(['A', 'E', 'F', 'C'], dtype=object)
```

Use `where` to determine whether that mapped value is used, or some `None`.  Use of `object` dtype allows for easy replacement of a string label with something else, `None` or `no_region`, etc.

```
In [62]: np.where(m, res, None)
Out[62]: array(['A', None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is a great and logical answer, one thing is I just converted ind in my question to `np.array(ind).ravel()` but otherwise a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do it efficiently, though not in a position to test right now:

```
rows = len(prediction)
p = prediction[np.arange(rows), catIndex.flatten()]
catResult = np.empty(rows, 'S1').fill('n')
catResult[p] = categories[catIndex.flatten()][p]
```